# MPMoviePlayerViewController iPad Memory Leak

Tags: ipad, memory, mpmovieplayercontroller, memory-leaks, mpmovieplayer

My movie player leaks memory only on the iPad and only when the "Done" button is clicked.  If the movie plays to completion then it cleans itself up properly.  Here is the play code:

```
mViewPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[self movieURL:@"mymovie"]];
[self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:mViewPlayer animated:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[mViewPlayer moviePlayer]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:[mViewPlayer moviePlayer]];
```

And here is the cleanup code:

```
- (void)exitedFullscreen:(NSNotification*)aNotification 
{
 MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:player];

 [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 NSLog(@"retainCount theMovie: %i", [mViewPlayer retainCount]); 
 player.initialPlaybackTime = -1;
 [player pause];
 [player stop];
 NSLog(@"retainCount theMovie: %i", [mViewPlayer retainCount]); 
 [player release];
 player = nil;
// [mViewPlayer release];
 mViewPlayer = nil;
}
```

retainCount is 3 both times it is printed above and is the same when the movie completes normally or when the "Done" button is clicked.

I have tried using MPMoviePlayerController as well with the same results.  I have tried using prepared play and 10 different methods to call the MPMoviePlayer*Controller, but it always leaks when I click the Done button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When removing observer the MPMoviePlayer instance has been retained with an autorelease. Wrapping the remove observer code with an autorelease will make the retainCount be as expected.

Like this:

```
// remove all observers
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; // following messages adds to autorelease pool
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:player];
[pool drain], pool = nil;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't seem to change anything.  However, thank you for the response.  It looks like this issue is not a problem in iPad 4.2 on the simulator and on the device.

Comment: well, checking retainCount on the object will be a lot easier now when you know you got the right number. You just have to find the place where it gets one retain too much.

Comment: The good news is that the iPad 4.2 on the simulator and on the device no longer leaks memory.  Definitely a bug in the 3.2 code.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to release the moviePlayer close to init. You could do it like this:

```
mViewPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[self movieURL:@"mymovie"]];
[self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:mViewPlayer animated:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[mViewPlayer moviePlayer]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:[mViewPlayer moviePlayer]];
[mViewPlayer release];
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need the player to be passed to my movie player exit code in my actual program and releasing it here crashed in my exit code.  Maybe this would work otherwise and not generate the 3 retain count.

Comment: if you release it like i said then you should not release it when dismissing the modalviewcontroller. the modalviewcontrol-display-thingy retains it, and when dismissed releases it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. To stop it without memory leak, I have to fast forward to the last few seconds so it can complete by itself.

But later i found out that this leak is only on the iPad Simulator. It is fine if you run it on device.